# how to query google fit api for nutrition

Tags: android, google-api, mapmyfitness

I've linked a myfitnesspal account to google and see the dataStreamId in the datasource list but, when I build the query using the oAuth 2.0 playground in google and try to query using:

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/raw:com.google.nutrition:com.myfitnesspal.android:food_item/datasets/1534723200000000000-1534982399000000000

I'm getting the following:

```
{
  "minStartTimeNs": "1534723200000000000", 
  "maxEndTimeNs": "1534982399000000000", 
  "dataSourceId": 
"raw:com.google.nutrition:com.myfitnesspal.android:food_item", 
  "point": []
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

MyFitnessPal sends batch data to Google Fit, once I day as far as I know, so if you entered food items today just for testing, you won't get them until tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I am getting no data with your request either, and I know I have data from many days before.